# Not Sequencial Array to JSON (Keys are string)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to create a custom array, with custom array keys.
Until here everything works well.

```
foreach ($results as $value){
        // $value['month'] is a string (varchar)
        $return[$value['month']]['working']     = $value['work_job'];

}
```

But, when i return this as json, i'm getting the follow situation.

```
"jobs": { // Here i need [ instead of {, how can i fix it?
"2": {
"working": "1"
},
"5": {
"working": "4"
},
"6": {
"working": "3"
}
} 

$return = array("jobs"  => $return,
                "testing"   => 'testing');
```

Tks

Comment: You don't don't show that code.  There is no _content_ or _jobs_.

Comment: Can you provide what you want the end result to look like?  simply changing the jobs to be an array would make the months invalid with that syntax.  So what end result are you wanting?

Comment: Basically, I don't think you can. JS arrays don't have non-sequential array afaict, so it generates you an object instead. Is that actually a problem?

Comment: But what about the month, are you wanting to preserve the month data?  Because if so that would possibly be jobs as an array containing objects/associative arrays with month as a key and working as another key.

Comment: @JonStirling already explained why it happens and what you can do. Deal with objects instead. If you can't then tell us why, so we can find a solution to your *real* problem.

Comment: Month is only numbers (1...12), it's not a complete month date

Comment: Jobs needs to be an array to be consumed by another platform!

Comment: @BrunoFontainha Then you need to provide an index for each month, even if the data is empty. No matter how much you want to deny it, what you're seeing from your code is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little concept issue in this.

In PHP, hashes or dictionaries are represented with arrays, not in other languages.

If your array is composed with this syntax

`$array['key'] = $value;`

It will be interpreted by the json encoder as an object. It will understand that $array is an object, 'key' is a property of $array and $value is the value of that property, being encoded like this.

`array = { key: value }`

Comment: This will probably confuse OP as you don't explain why non sequential integer keys in PHP won't encode the same way as sequential integer keys.

Comment: @BrunoFontainha I already explained in the comments on your question.... JS doesn't have non-sequential arrays.

Comment: @BrunoFontainha Oh come on, I also told you a solution _in the comments on your question_.

Comment: @Jon Sirling I understood your answer very well Thanks a lot!